# Как добавить переменную в запрос?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Есть запрос, нужно добавить переменную:

```
var1 = 'Тест'
query = "SELECT * from table where value = %s)"
args = (var1)
cur.execute(query, args)
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Выводит ошибку:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перечислю ошибки:

1. лишняя / непарная закрывающая скобка в конце SQL строки
2. по-моему, `cx_Oracle` не поддерживает `%s` шаблона
3. `args = (var1)` - является строкой, а не кортежем. Для того чтобы получился кортеж надо делать так: `args = (var1,)`. NOTE: обратите внимание на запятую.

Попробуйте так:

```
var1 = 'Тест'
query = "SELECT * from table where value = :val"
args = (var1, ) # или: [var1], т.е. передавать надо либо список либо кортеж
cur.execute(query, args)
```

---

[Из документации `cx-Oracle`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html):

> SQL and PL/SQL statements that pass data to and from Oracle Database
> should use placeholders in SQL and PL/SQL statements that mark where
> data is supplied or returned. These placeholders are referred to as
> `bind variables` or `bind parameters`.

> A `bind variable` is a
> **colon-prefixed identifier or numeral**.

Т.е. либо так:

```
select * from table where col1_name = :col1 and col2_name = :col2
```

либо так:

```
select * from table where col1_name = :1 and col2_name = :2
```

Comment: спасибо, вы лучший!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!